# Уолт чи Волт? Вільям чи Уільям?

Tags: переклад, from-english, власні-назви, запозичені-слова, іноземні-імена

Як правильно вживати: Уолт чи Волт Дісней, Вільям чи Уільям Шекспір? Незважаючи на офіційне вживання букви «В» на початку даних імен, часто використовується і «У». Як правильніше? Чи можна стовідсотково стверджувати, що лише одна з форм подібних імен правильна? Чи допустиме вживання двох форм таких власних назв? Чи не є Уолт, Уільям калькою з російської?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Коротко

**Правильно:**

> - [**В**ільям Шекспір](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BC_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80);
> - [**В**олт Дісней](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82_%D0%94%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9).

**Але** деякі инші слова з буквою **w** за чинним правописом таки „зберегли“ написання через **у**, що є калькою з московської.

## Оріґінал

Всі позначаються через букву **w**:

- **W**illiam Shakespeare;
- **W**alt Disney.

## Правописи

### Чинний — 2015 — правопис

> #### [§ 97](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par97).
>
> Англійське **w** у власних назвах передається звичайно через **в**: *Вашингтон*, *Вебстер*, *Веллінгтон*, *Вільсон*, ***Вільямс***, *Вінер*, *Вінніпег* та ін., але за традицією *Уайльд*, *Уеллс*, *Уельс*, *Уолл-стрит*, *Голсуорсі*, *Хемінгуей* та ін.;

*Для порівняння:*

### Клясичниь правопис — 1928

> #### [§ 60. Англійське W](//r2u.org.ua/node/243)
>
> Англійське **w** і перед голосними передаємо через **в** (а не через **у**): *Вайлд* (не *Уальд*), *Вайт* (не *Уайт*), *Велз* (не *Уельс*), *Вітман* (не *Уітман*), *Віклеф* (не *Уїклеф*), *Вестмінстер* (не *Уестмінстер*), *ват*, *кіловат* і т. ін.

## Фонетіка

[Московська мова](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology) не має звуку букви [**w**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W#English) — **[w]**, тому вони намагається передавати через **в** з **[v]** та **у** з **[u]** чи **[ʊ]**. А [українська](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology) має і це буква **в**.

Навіть колись в правопису — [Русалки Дністрової](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%94%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97) — пропонувалось це писати через [**ў**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%8E#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), так само як зараз білоруська.

Comment: Якщо даєте рекомендацію щодо офіційного правопису то наводьте приклади користуючись тим самим правописом, бо виходить щось неочевидне.

Comment: Перепрошую якщо коментар видався різким - насправді це коментар до мого редагування посту - я пояснюю чому замінив "Вільӓм" на "Вільям". Я не вимагаю щоб весь пост був написаний чинним правописом.

Answer (score 5):

Поясню докладніше, що означає [«російська мова не має літери, яка б позначала звук [w], тому вони намагаються передавати його через *в* або *у*, а українська має — і це са́ме літера *в*» у відповіді Follower](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3050).

Річ у тім, що росіяни і українці зазвичай не зовсім однаково читають літеру *в*:

- Росіяни нормативно читають літеру *в* як [[v]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), або, якщо вона перед глухою приголосною чи остання у слові, як [[f]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (плюс ще м'які/пом'якшені варіанти).
- В українців значно більша варіативність читання літери *в*. У залежності від позиції в слові, оточуючих звуків і діалекту це може бути: [[β̞]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), [[ʋ]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), [[w], [u̯]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) і навіть [[ʍ]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_labialized_velar_approximant).

  Також її можуть вимовляти і як [[v]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) чи навіть [[f]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), аналогічно до росіян, але це зазвичай вважається відхиленням від стандартної практики / суржиком.

  Звуки [[β̞]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) і [[ʋ]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), що використовуються в українській мові у більшості випадків (перший — у більшості випадків перед голосними, а другий часто перед *і* /і/), вже виглядають трішки ближчими до [[w]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), ніж «класичний» (англійський і російський) [[v]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Щодо [[w] і [u̯]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), які можуть (хоча, мабуть, і не мусять) уживатися перед *о* /ɔ/ та *у* /u/, а також перед приголосним (після голосного) та на кінці слова (після голосного), то вони є фактично еквивалентом «класичного» (англійського) [[w]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82).

Таким чином, зважаючи на те, що літера *в* в українській мові може позначати звук [[w]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) і схожі до нього принаймні в деяких позиціях у слові (а в деяких діалектах — ще частіше), транслітерування *w* через *в* в українській мові виглядає доречнішим, ніж у російській (тому якщо в російській *w* транслітерують через *у* та *в* порівну або з перехилом до *у*, то в українській мові обґрунтованішим виглядає перехил до *в*).

*Звуки, взято з [статті](//zbruc.eu/node/41931) · [Ореста Друля](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)*

[image: Звуки]

<sub>Також додам, що користувач Follower сам експериментує з нестандартними способами письма, тому його:</sub>

> <sub>правильно: ***В**ільӓм Шекспір*; ***В**олт Діснеь*</sub>

<sub>— радше сприймати як:</sub>

> <sub>правильно: ***В**ільям Шекспір*; ***В**олт Дісней*</sub>

<sub>— аніж буквально.</sub>

<sub>Він хотів наголосити, що згідно до сучасного правопису треба здебільшого *в*, а не *у* (але при цьому за своїм особистим звичаєм вжив нестандартні *‑ьӓ-* й *‑еь* замість *‑ья-* й *‑ей*).</sub>